# SSL Configration on Docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, ubuntu, ssl, containers

I want to host .Net ASP Core projects using Docker and Kubernetes on Ubuntu 20.04 server. What server type should we choose before integrate the SSL?  (SSL :  Comodo EV SSL) I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "server type"? How is the server related to SSL?

Comment: when you say 'server type' do you mean Docker images or is it something else.? Please provide more information on this.

Comment: @jAC While i am uploading the CSR, the company where i bought  SSL, wants me to choose server type and I do not know how to choose. 
These are the some options for server type : 
- AOL 
- Apache + MOD SSL
- Apache + Raven
- IBM HTTP
- Microsoft IIS 4.X - 5.X - 6.X - 7.X - 8.X 
- Oracle
- Plesk
- Citrix

Comment: @Vinod I want to integrate my SSL to my Ubuntu Server 20.04, and that Ubuntu Server has docker on it. In that docker, i have different containers, i need to integrate the SSL. While im trying create CSR, the company where i bought SSL, wants me to choose server type. So, i do not know how to choose. These are the some options for server type :  - AOL - Apache + MOD SSL - Apache + Raven - IBM HTTP - Microsoft IIS 4.X - 5.X - 6.X - 7.X - 8.X - Oracle - Plesk - Citrix –

Comment: I'm unsure what the specific output is, but I guess that the provider simply needs that info to provide you with a compliant certificate type. Some web servers use plain X509 while others use encoded formats like DER or else. 
Anyhow with openssl you can convert the certificate to whichever format you want.
Are you using ASP.NET Core inbuilt Kestrel web server? If so, it will accept PFX keystores similar to IIS. So I guess IIS should be the correct answer.

Comment: @jAC  I'm quite new in this container world and Docker. I pull sql image and trial api and run them, i mapped the ports so i can reach my sql server from outside. Do you have any suggestions about the web server that i may use in my docker images? I just want to use containers for the APIs and SQL. 
Furthermore, Certificate type is POSITIVESSLEV. I dont understand why but they want to know the server type?

Comment: oh so server type we use when we download certificate. i mean where you are going to host your server like on tomcat or apache  or widows IIS according to that you have to choose server type. docker images for web server you can use any official image from docker hub.  you have offical image of  apache, tomcat, windows IIS etc
for ref: https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat